# Low Search and category keywords

Tags: categories, low-search

Although I've used Low Search in the past, I now have a need to include category keywords in the results.

In the past I've used the standard category dropdown approach to refine (filter) the results to a specific category...

> You can use the native category parameter to filter by category.

ref: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#categories

But the docs clearly state that category keyword searching is possible and that seems to be the whole point of having categories within the create collections, and that it can pick up keywords within category description, title, or custom field...

> Low Search can also add category information to the index, making
>   entries searchable by keywords present in their categories.

ref: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/collections#categories

So I have a category with the title "Dog Friendly", I've included this in the collection and run a search on "dog". No results. "Dog", "friendly", "Dog Friendly" - all no results (I have tried rebuilding indexes).

If I wanted to just do a search on a specific category, I'd using the category ID from a dropdown, so is irrelevant to title, keyword, description, etc - so I'm assuming that's not what the documentation is referring to. Also not an option as I have hundreds of categories.

I've even tried adding the word "testing" to a category description, then run a search for "testing" and included a dropdown category select with the relevant category selected. Still no results.

What am I doing wrong?

- EE v2.7.2
- Low Search v3.1.5

Other StackExchange Answers:

[Can Low Search keywords also search in categories?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13891/can-low-search-keywords-also-search-in-categories/13896#13896)

[Index Categories in Expression Engine search results](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/index-categories-in-expression-engine-search-results)

Comment: I will need further info to investigate, and I think my [GetSatisfaction support page](https://getsatisfaction.com/low) is better suited here, as this is not really a "how-to" question. Could you post to GetSat and add a screenshot of the search collection settings you're referring to and post your Form and Results tag in a Pastie? Add a URI of a search not generating the right results, too. Thanks.

Comment: ah, ooops - missed that big link on the site docs stating "support" - erk.

Answer (score 3):

The cause turned out to be the creation (and rebuild) of the indexes not including category information.  This build also included Publisher and included an [extension to add Publisher support to Low Search](https://github.com/litzinger/publisher_low_search), which it seems doesn't support categories - I've created a ticket with the developer, so hopefully this will get resolved soon.